# Tabledrag in Drupal 7 admin pages only working in Firefox

Tags: 7

For some reason, in the last couple of days any table that is tabledrag enabled (in core admin interfaces like the menu editor, as well as custom modules) only works in Firefox.

In IE and Chrome there are no errors reported in the console, the row is highlighted on mousedown, but nothing happens when you drag.

Has anyone else encountered this and know of a fix?

Comment: Can you give us any more background? Have you made any changes in the past couple of days? Performed any updates to the site? Are you experiencing this only on the backend? Does switching the admin theme fix anything?

Comment: Thanks, Jance. It was an issue introduced in version 7.52 and resolved by upgrading to 7.53.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a regression introduced in 7.52 related to dragging in the admin interface. It's fixed in the 7.53 release. It may be as simple as upgrading to the latest version of core.

The 7.53 release page, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.53.

Comment: I can confirm that we were on version 7.52, and upgrading to a newer version did the trick. Thank you!